# Wilsonian renormalisation / Polchinski renormalisation equation. Why is the factor in the kinetic term infinite for large momenta?

Tags: renormalization, effective-field-theory

For Polchinski renormalisation equation, a smooth cutoff is introduced that is essentially a factor of $ 1 $ up until the cutoff region in the kinetic term. Beyond this "cutting-off" region (where the function is smoothly interpolated) instead of reaching the value $ 0 $, the factor is infinite.

For example the integrand of the kinetic term would be modified into $ \phi(p)\phi(-p)(p^2+m^2) (K(p^2))^{-1} $, where $K(p^2)=1$ for $ p^2 $ under the cutoff region and $ K(p^2)=0 $ above the cutoff. Why is the factor $ K^{-1} $ rather than just $ K $?

I reckon the answers lies in the following comment from [these notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.07763) explaining the introduction of this factor:

> such that Fourier modes for $ p^2 > k^2 $ dominate the path integral and are thus preferentially integrated out.

But I can't make sense of it. Does this mean that somehow the integration of this infinite factor "cancels out"? How?